# VBA SheetChange EnableEvents Error on Double Click

Tags: excel, vba, events

Running into a weird error when trying to disable the "EnableEvents" during the SheetChange event.

Imagine cell A1 with a list validation with the options "Yes", "No".

If the user double clicks on the cell, but then immediately afterward decides to select either the "Yes" or "No" value I get the following error:

> Run-time error '50290': Method'EnableEvents' of object '_Application'
>   failed

It works fine others. Only get this error, when the user does this (which isn't often, but users do what they do).

The error protection doesn't work because it too has the EnableEvents call thee because I have to ensure to re-enable the events afterward. I tried adding 'On Error Remove Next' after the error handler, but that didn't work

Here's the main code: **EDITED**

Class Module named 'AppObject'

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)
On Error GoTo ExitProcedure

    App.EnableEvents = False

    Call RunMySheetChangeProcedure

ExitProcedure:
    App.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Standard Module named 'ModuleAppIni'

```
Public MyAppObject As AppObject

Sub Auto_Open()
    Set MyAppObject = New AppObject
End Sub

Sub DestroyMe()
    Set MyAppObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: (a) I assume you renamed `ThisWorkbook` to `App`.  (b) `EnableEvents` is a property of the `Application` object.  It isn't a `Workbook` property.

Comment: No, even if you renamed `ThisWorkbook` to `App`, that should still be `Workbook_SheetChange`.  What is `App` defined as?  Where is it defined?  Where is your code located?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've added a fuller example of my code to maybe answer your questions.

Comment: (a) Why do you want to have a second `Application` object? (b) What are you doing to invoke the `App_SheetChange` procedure?  Are you calling that from a `Workbook_SheetChange` event?  If so, is that workbook open in the `App` application or in the standard `Application`? (c) When the code crashes, does an `App` object exist, or is it still `Nothing`? (I assume it does exist, but it's best to ask.)

Comment: Take a look at my edited OP which should answer your questions. (a) I only have one Application object named "App". The MyAppObject variable is a reference to the class object (which in turn uses a app object) (b) When the Application's SheetChange  event occurs, the associated procedure is invoked. I'm using the Applications's sheet change event - not the workbooks. (c) The App object does exist.

Comment: My apologies - I read `Set App = Application` as `Set App = New Application`.

Answer (score 0):

try .IgnoreBlank = False

```
    With Range("A1").Validation
        'other parameters
        .IgnoreBlank = False
    End With
```